# Simple calculator using two textboxes to be used for square in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code:

```
    <html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="CalculatorController">
      Enter a number:
      <input type="number" ng-model="number" />
      <br /> Enter a number:
      <input type="number" ng-model="number2" />
      <br />
      <div>
        <button ng-click="doSquare()">X<sup>2</sup></button>
        <button ng-click="doCube()">X<sup>3</sup></button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div>
        <button ng-click="doAdd()">Add</button>
        <button ng-click="doSubstract()">Substract</button>
        <button ng-click="doMultiply()">Multiply</button>
        <button ng-click="doDivide()">Divide</button>
        <button ng-click="doModulus()">Modulus</button>
      </div>
      <div>Answer: {{answer}}</div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" ng-click="clear('filter')">Clear</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.service('MathService', function() {
      this.add = function(a, b) {
        return a + b
      };

      this.substract = function(a, b) {
        return a - b
      };

      this.multiply = function(a, b) {
        return a * b
      };

      this.divide = function(a, b) {
        return a / b
      };

      this.modulus = function(a, b) {
        return a % b
      };
    });

    app.service('CalculatorService', function(MathService) {

      this.square = function(a) {
        return MathService.multiply(a, a);
      };
      this.cube = function(a) {
        return MathService.multiply(a, MathService.multiply(a, a));
      };
      this.add = function(a, b) {
        return MathService.add(a, b);
      };
      this.substract = function(a, b) {
        return MathService.substract(a, b);
      };
      this.multiply = function(a, b) {
        return MathService.multiply(a, b);
      };
      this.divide = function(a, b) {
        return MathService.divide(a, b);
      };
      this.modulus = function(a, b) {
        return MathService.modulus(a, b);
      };
    });

    app.controller('CalculatorController', function($scope, CalculatorService) {

      $scope.doSquare = function() {
        $scope.answer = CalculatorService.square($scope.number);
        $scope.answer = CalculatorService.square($scope.number2);
      }

      $scope.doCube = function() {
        $scope.answer = CalculatorService.cube($scope.number);
        $scope.answer = CalculatorService.cube($scope.number2);
      }
      $scope.doAdd = function() {
        $scope.answer = CalculatorService.add($scope.number, $scope.number2);
      }
      $scope.doSubstract = function() {
        $scope.answer = CalculatorService.substract($scope.number, $scope.number2);
      }
      $scope.doMultiply = function() {
        $scope.answer = CalculatorService.multiply($scope.number, $scope.number2);
      }
      $scope.doDivide = function() {
        $scope.answer = CalculatorService.divide($scope.number, $scope.number2);
      }
      $scope.doModulus = function() {
        $scope.answer = CalculatorService.modulus($scope.number, $scope.number2);
      }
      $scope.clear = function(answer) {
       $scope.answer = null; 
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I give input to first textbox and by clicking X^2 i should get the answer and when I will give the input to 2nd textbox and then also by clicking the X^2 I should get the answer.
How to do that?
Can anyone help me out?
Here is the plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/8Y47MDICWdeBTiJzaUnP?p=preview

Comment: you have to include if condition in x^2 function to check which textbox is fill and execute that ..

Comment: Side note: Parse `$scope.number` and `$scope.number2` to number  before invoking the service methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I give input to first textbox and by clicking X^2 i should get the answer and when I will give the input to 2nd textbox and then also by clicking the X^2 I should get the answer. How to do that?

You can utilize `||` (or) operator.

```
$scope.doSquare = function() {
    $scope.answer = CalculatorService.square($scope.number) || 
                    CalculatorService.square($scope.number2);
}
```

It might not be the best way and I might not be fully convinced with how it should behave, but this would solve your problem.

Note that, with this code, if first textbox has value present, it won't go for second.

Comment: @neo.abi1000 simplest way would be to have two answers and showing both when both values are present.. should be simple to implement for you